# Can Azure function's binding let message passing as buffer or with specific encoding

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I use azure function to save message from an eventhub to azure table. But I am stucked by some encoding problem.

My scenario is one process is sending an ascii encoding buffer to eventhub, then the azure function save it into the table.
However, the azure function get parameter from eventhub becomes a UTF8 string. This causes some invalid UTF8 bytes loose.

Now I doubt can I solve the problem in the following two ways:

1. Can the bindings setting let the trigger's parameter from eventhub to azure function to be a buffer rather than a string. Here I get started with the nodejs template.
2. Or, the bindings let the object to string with specific encoding. Then I can re-construct the buffer again.

Or there is another better way to solve this?

Comment: @mathewc Can you help me :(

Comment: Mathew is on vacation, but @pragna-gopa has you covered! :)

Comment: @FabioCavalcante thanks for your help. But I wonder there is a way for nodejs to specify the parameter's type?

Comment: For Node, you can set the dataType property to binary.
See an example here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/1ab54a94916c8180105af1e43b24a483f070a53f/test/WebJobs.Script.Tests/TestScripts/Node/HttpTriggerByteArray/function.json#L7

Pragna can update the answer with the Node information so it may be appropriately marked and help others.

Comment: Yes! It do the great things! Thank you very much. I think the [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-event-hubs/#trigger-usage) should also be updated. It only mentions the string case.

Comment: The team is actively working to update the docs with that information! :) In the meantime, Pragna has updated the answer below with all the details needed, so feel free to mark that so it can help others as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bindings support byte arrays. Here is an c# example :

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public static void Run(byte[] myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    string s1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myEventHubMessage);
    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {s1}");
}
```

And for Node set the datatype to binary. Sample function.json

```
{
     "bindings": [
        {
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "name": "req",
            "direction": "in",
            "dataType": "binary"
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "name": "res",
            "direction": "out"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Corresponding index.js:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var body = req.body;

    context.log("TestResult:", {
        isBuffer: Buffer.isBuffer(body),
        length: body.length
    });

    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: "Success!"
    };

    context.done();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How about the nodejs case? I cannot specific the type in parameter.

Comment: Add something to completement, the DataType can be one of {string, binary, stream}, the string is default value.